# Someone who exploits your feelings for them to take advantage of you

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, idioms

I need a word or idiom for someone who takes advantage of you because they know you like them. In relationships, I heard the word "user", as someone who uses their romantic partners for material gain.

More specifically, I'm thinking of someone who guesses what kind of people you like and then acts like that until you like them and start offering yourself to help with various things they need. Edit: for this one I could do with a name of a famous character from a novel.

Comment: Deception is the first general word that comes to mind. If it's a woman doing it, gold digger is a good one.

Comment: It's general, but "manipulator" might be what you need.

Comment: One answer is again, quite often overlooked, in your question. Try "exploiter."

Comment: One who takes advantage of you because they know you like them might be a "user" a "cheat" or a "fraud", among other things.

Yes, in relationships, a "user" can be someone who "uses" their romantic partners for material gain but to be clear "material gain" explains little. One who "uses" romantic partners for gain is more likely to be using those partners for sexual gratification.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of a literary character, Becky Sharp in Thackeray's Vanity Fair may fit the bill, or possibly Wickham in Austen's Pride and Prejudice?
Both are characters who use their personal charms to exploit others. 
Collins dictionary suggests such a character may be a 'picaroon': a person who lives by his or her wits.

Answer (score 1):

*for this one I could do with a name of a famous character from a novel.*

From Merriam Webster:

> **Svengali** noun
>
> Sven·​ga·​li | \ sven-ˈgä-lē  , sfen- \
>
> *Definition of Svengali*: **a person who manipulates or exerts excessive control over another**
>
> In George du Maurier's 1894 novel Trilby, a young artist's model named Trilby O'Ferrall falls under the spell of Svengali, a villainous
> musician and hypnotist. Svengali trains Trilby's voice through hypnosis and transforms her into a singing star, subjugating her completely in the process. Svengali's maleficent powers of persuasion made such an impression on the reading public that by 1919 his name was being used generically as a term for any wickedly manipulative individual.

1972   *Maclean's* March. 41/2   *He had a strange hypnotic power—not that he was a Svengali, but when he spoke people listened.*

Answer (score 0):

How about "manipulative"? Someone is manipulative if they manipulate you, fully well knowing your feelings towards them, and then exploiting those feelings for their gain, pecuniary or otherwise.

Sounds like a mild case of narcissistic sociopathy as well, but I'm no psychologist.

Comment: manipulator, the person has asked for a noun.

Answer (score 0):

> [**cozener**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/cozener) noun: (Merriam Webster)
>
> a dishonest person who uses clever means to cheat others out of
> something of value
>
> [**cozen** verb:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cozen) (Merriam Webster)
>
> 1: to deceive, win over, or induce to do something by artful coaxing
> and wheedling or shrewd trickery
>
> 2: to gain by cozening someone

cozened his supper out of the old couple

Comment: Does anyone use "to cozen" nowadays? I associate it with Shakespeare.

Answer (score -1):

I'd strongly suggest that you stick to the word ''**exploiter**'' but there are other terms used or accepted in several situations suggested below.

The word [phony](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Phony) means a person who pretends to be someone else or to have feelings or abilities that he or she does not really have and it would fit your description only because nobody would go through the effort it takes to be phony without the possibility of material gains.

Another word is [charlatan](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/charlatan), which means a person who falsely pretends to know or be something in order to deceive people or simply put, a phony person. 
One could say '' My new friend turned out to a charlatan.''

Then there is [confidence man](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/confidence%20man) used mostly in US which, as the name suggests, is someone who tricks you after he has gained your confidence.

Comment: con men take advantage of anyone at all. Nothing to do with whether or not you like them.

Comment: Most obviously, one who exploits your feelings to take advantage of you is simply a "user".

If someone exploiting your feelings had an obvious idiomatic equivalent, how would that be tied to "because they knew you liked them"? Is that phrase the whole point, or just a waste of space and time? 

FYI a "user" is indeed one who takes advantage of romantic partners for gain, and that gain need not be material… more likely, for instance, that gain would be sexual…